# WCF MaxConcurrentCalls

Tags: wcf

The default WCF MaxConcurrentCalls=16. My demo app shows this to be 32. Is this because I have a dual core machine? ie MaxConcurrentCalls=16*[# of cores] ?

Comment: Documentation doesn't say anything immediately obvious about that. Can you possibly post your demo code? Might be something happening in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using .NET 4.0? Because that was exactly one of the changes in the throttling behaviors that were introduced in WCF 4.0. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/07/26/wcf-4-higher-default-throttling-settings-for-wcf-services.aspx) for details.